# Passing parameters to class that implements LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

One of my JSF receives parameters through metadata and f:ViewParm tag.  I am using these parameters in the backing bean in pre-render view to query on the database and build my list for the datatable view. It is working fine but now I need to switch to lazyDataModel (I am using Primefaces 3.2). If I follow the examples, then I need to implement LazyDataModel which is done in the constructor of the backing bean.  I can do that but then I do not have access to the parameters. My question is how can I grab the parameters and pass to my class which implements LazyDataModel (say LazyCarDataModel). I want to use those parameters in the overridden load method of LazyCarDataModel.  There is no way I can have access to incoming parameters in my constructor. Any suggestions/tricks to handle this situation will be appreciated.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<f:event type="preRenderView">` to invoke a backing bean method after the view parameters have been set.

E.g.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="carId" value="#{bean.car}" converter="#{carConverter}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
private Car car;
private transient DataModel<Something> model;

public void init() {
    model = buildSomehowBasedOn(car);
}
```

You could alternatively also introduce lazy loading in the getter of the datatable.

```
public DataModel<Something> getModel() {
    if (model == null) {
        model = buildSomehowBasedOn(car);
    }

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and have a wonderful weekend. Your help is always appreciated by many.